# Adding #to_yaml to DataMapper models

Tags: ruby, yaml, psych

I am using DataMapper for Database access. My goal is to send the models to an webservice as read-only object. This is my current try:

```
class User
  include DataMapper::Resource

  def to_yaml(opts = {})
    mini_me = OpenStruct.new
    instance_variables.each do |var|
      next if /^@_/ =~ var.to_s
      mini_me.send("#{var.to_s.gsub(/^@/, '')}=", instance_variable_get(var))
    end

    mini_me.to_yaml(opts)
  end

  ....
end

YAML::ENGINE.yamler = 'psych'

u = User.get("hulk")
p u.to_yaml
# => "--- !ruby/object:OpenStruct\ntable:\n  :uid: hulk\n  :uidNumber: 1000\n  :gidNumber: 1001\n  :email: hulk@example.com\n  :dn: uid=hulk,ou=People,o=example\n  :name: Hulk\n  :displayName: Hulk\n  :description: Hulk\n  :homeDirectory: /home/hulk\n  :accountFlags: ! '[U          ]'\n  :sambaSID: S-1-5-21-......\nmodifiable: true\n" 

p [ u ].to_yaml # TypeError: can't dump anonymous class Class
```

Any ideas how to make this work and get rid of the exception?

Thanks,
krissi

Comment: `p [ u ].map(&:to_yaml)`

Comment: This doesn't work. It gives me an array of yamls. When I yaml the array Ill get the yaml-strings yaml'd. And it works for exactly this layer, but I need a clean way which works everywhere

Comment: then you have to monkey patch Array and put a `to_yaml`method there

Comment: Array does support #to_yaml: `[:coffee].to_yaml` works as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`to_yaml` is deprecated in Psych](https://github.com/tenderlove/psych/blob/v1.3.2/lib/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb#L87), and from my testing it seems to be actually broken in cases like this.

When you call `to_yaml` directly on your object, your method gets called and you get the result you expect. When you call it on the array containing your object, Psych serializes it but doesn’t correctly handle your `to_yaml` method, and ends up falling back onto the default serialization. In your case this results in an attempt to serialize an anonymous Class which causes the error.

To fix this, you should use the `encode_with` method instead. If it’s important that the serialized form is tagged as an OpenStruct object in the generated yaml you can use the `represent_object` (that first `nil` parameter doesn’t seem to be used):

```
def encode_with(coder)
  mini_me = OpenStruct.new
  instance_variables.each do |var|
    next if /^@_/ =~ var.to_s
    mini_me.send("#{var.to_s.gsub(/^@/, '')}=", instance_variable_get(var))
  end

  coder.represent_object(nil, mini_me)
end
```

If you were just using OpenStruct for convenience, an alternative could be something like:

```
def encode_with(coder)
  instance_variables.each do |var|
    next if /^@_/ =~ var.to_s
    coder[var.to_s.gsub(/^@/, '')]= instance_variable_get(var)
  end
end
```

Note that [Datamapper has its own serializer plugin](https://github.com/datamapper/dm-serializer) that provides yaml serialization for models, it might be worth looking into.

Comment: Thanks, great answer. Ill keep with the struct because I want the dots (user_foo.uid). It took me some struggling with the included psych version (which does not respond to `represent_object` but I fixed it with bundler and everythings fine now ;)

Comment: @krissi What version of Ruby are you using? It looks like `represent_object` was added for 1.9.3, but isn’t in 1.9.2. Anyway, if you can’t upgrade Ruby you can use Psych from the gem like you’ve discovered.

Comment: Ah okay, I use 1.9.2. I do the upgrade :)